# fabric-samples chaincode-docker-devmode does not work

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From `git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git`,the example **chaincode-docker-devmode** ,when I execute `docker-compose-simple.yaml` ,from `docker ps` comand ,there is no cli docker ,and I saw the errors followng :

> cli          | Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST .
>     cli          | Usage:
>     cli          | peer channel create [flags] .
>     peer         | 2017-08-22 02:38:47.816 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 187 [0b52bba4]Init get response status: 200
>   cli            |
>   cli            | Flags:
>   cli            |   -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.

It seems the official example could not work.
I realize the script.sh file , `peer channel create -c myc -f myc.tx -o orderer:7050` throw BAD_REQUEST Error.

Comment: Could be the creation of the channel being executed twice?

Comment: Yes,I forget to annotation the command about cli in docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the the genesis block (orderer.block) and the more importantly the channel create transaction (myc.tx) were generated for/with v1.0.0.
There was a bug in v1.0.0 which was fixed in v1.0.1.  Unfortunately while existing channels will continue to work if you simply upgrade the orderer node(s), the artifacts generated by configtxgen v1.0.0 will not work with v1.0.1 of Hyperledger Fabric.  I've submitted a patch for this ( https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/13069/ ) and waiting for it to be merged.  In the meantime, you can clone the master branch of the fabric-samples and pull down the patch.

Edit:  this fix is now merged and available if you clone / update your clone of the fabric-samples repo